# Use select2 ajax data to update hidden inputs

Tags: ajax, object, jquery-select2

I am having trouble updating hidden inputs using data retrieved from Select2 Ajax.
Please see my code:

```
var select2_town = $('.select-test select').select2({

ajax: {
url : ajax_var.url, 
dataType: 'json',
type: 'post',
delay: 250,
data: function (params) {
  return {
    q: params.term, // search term
    page: params.page,
  };
},
processResults: function (data, page) {
  return {
   results: $.map(data, function (item) {
        return {
            id: item.id, //eg 1149
            town: item.place_name, //eg Reading
            county: item.county, //eg Berkshire
            country: item.country,
            data: item
        };
    })
  };
},
cache: true;
},
   escapeMarkup: function (markup) { return markup; },
  minimumInputLength: 1,
 templateResult: function (item) { return ('<p>' + item.town + ' - ' +   item.county + '</p>'); },
 templateSelection:  function (item) { return (item.town); },
});
```

This code works fine for me. My issue is what happens after a value is selected.

I would like to update my hidden input ids "#town","#county" and "#country" with town,county and country respectively through an 'change' event.

I have seen many SO examples but they all stop at `$(this).select2('data')[0];`but do not expand on it.

Weird thing is that the following script displays the correct value in console log. but ALWAYS only apply the object id to #country.

```
select2_town.on('change', function() {
var obz = $(this).select2('data')[0].country;
  console.log(obz);//displays Reading in console
 $("#country").attr("value",obz); //displays 1149
});
```

Comment: can you create a sample here on http://jsfiddle.net for this please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This actually works.

I had another function that was adding the ID hidden in another file. I deleted that and then the script worked as I wanted it to.

Regards

Thanks